# Move Subquery in the where clause to a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get the top 1 order by using this query:

```
select  top 1 ID
From    MyTable
Where   userid = @userid
and     ((type = 'SomeValue1' and status in (1,2) and convert(date,create_date) < convert(date,getdate())) OR
         (type = 'SomeValue2' and status in (1,3) and convert(date,create_date) < convert(date,getdate())) OR
         (type = 'SomeValue2' and status not in (1,3) and convert(date,create_date) = convert(date,getdate())))
and     active = 1
order by convert(date,create_date)
```

Is there a way, I can move the conditions in the where clause after the 1st "AND", where I compare the "type", "status" and "Create_Date" to a table and use it in the where clause? The reason I'm asking is, I have to do a number of such comparisons and it would get clunky to have like 30 different lines in there for one query.

Also , let me know, if I'm going this the totally wrong way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could put those in a table but then you are forced to use dynamic sql. Also, you state you want top 1 but there is no order by clause so you have no way of determining which row you will get.

Comment: @SeanLange: Sorry. I forgot to add "Order by". Would you mind telling me how to do the table and dynamic query? Sorry.. I'm new to this.

Comment: At just 30, if these are static, it's probably not better than just writing them in the query. If these conditions will change often, that's when you want to start looking at making them become actual data.

Comment: Also, this is **very** inefficient code: `convert(date,create_date) < convert(date,getdate())`. The problem is it prevents the database from using any indexes you might have for the `create_date` column, and the database will need to call that function for **every record** in the table, even if the column value is nowhere close to the current date. Think about how you could do this without needing to call a function against the `create_date` column.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn actually a convert to date on a datetime column is one of those rare cases where it is sargable.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. Only my recommendations:

```
DECLARE @today date = cast(sysdatetime() AS date);

select top(1) ID
From    MyTable
Where   userid = @userid
and     ((type = 'SomeValue1' and status in (1,2) and cast(create_date AS date) < @today) OR
         (type = 'SomeValue2' and status in (1,3) and cast(create_date AS date) < @today) OR
         (type = 'SomeValue2' and status not in (1,3) and cast(create_date AS date) = @today))
and     active = 1
ORDER BY x
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

- Then add filtered index on `userid`, `type`, `status` and `create_date` `WHERE active = 1`